# Who invented the "Run to the president" scene

Tags: first-appearance, cinematography

In many movies you can find a scene where something big just happened and someone starts running to the president (or another important person) to report it.

In that scene you can see a floor-near camera follow the steps of someone running towards a door.

The earliest movie I could find that scene was in [The Right Stuff](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086197/) from 1983 where Jeff Goldblum runs. But who invented that scene in the first place?

[image: screenshot]